# Devise sign out not signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm having trouble signing out with devise. I am creating my signout link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

This was causing problems because the route could not be found so I added this to my routes.rb:

```
get 'sign_out', :to => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```

Which does't cause any errors but also doesn't sign out, `user_signed_in?` still returns true.

Any ideas?

Comment: try 'devise/sessions#destroy'

Answer (score 1):

try
 `delete "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"` and

`<%= link_to "Sign out", logout_path, :method => :delete %>`

Comment: I can't get this working with the delete verb as I would want, but changing the route to devise/sessions#destroy works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be a DELETE request, which can be accomplished like this,

```
<%= link_to("Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

This won't require you to add anything to your routes (assuming you have already added devise routes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sign out link, it works for me

change your sign out link to

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```