# Devise Not Signing Out From ERB Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app with a Devise login system for a domain and all the subdomains.  It was working properly before, but now the sign out function isn't working for some reason.

I have tried this as my sign out link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Or, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240240/devise-sign-out-not-signing-out), this as my sign out link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", logout_path, :method => :delete %>
```

With this in my routes:

```
devise_scope :user do
  delete "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
end
```

Either way, I click the link and get something like this in my server:

```
Started DELETE "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-19 23:09:51 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"tbFG+joMI84Z/fu9YxCTDj+2Ltp8Wm0tC8ClirXIL4Z8+e7xuePzbn0cPyY0Ljj/UA1rxO+q3WFuO3BNHMJXTQ=="}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://lvh.me:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-19 23:09:51 -0800
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (66.5ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 107ms (Views: 106.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Yet the session persists.  Here's my entire routing file, if it helps:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users, only: [:show]
  devise_scope :user do
      delete "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
    end

    constraints subdomain: 'liz' do
        scope module: 'liz', as: 'liz' do
            get 'home/index'
            root 'home#index'
            resources :inquiries
            resources :blogs
            get 'tags/:tag', to: 'blogs#index', as: :tag
            get 'services/hire'
            get 'services/dev'
            get 'services/design'
            get 'services/branding'
            get 'services/portfolio'
        end
    end

    constraints subdomain: 'anthony' do
        scope module: 'anthony', as: 'anthony' do
            get 'home/index'
            root 'home#index'
        end
    end

    get 'home/index'
    root 'home#index'
    resources :logs
end
```

Here are my user-related routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                  logout DELETE /logout(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
```

I don't know where else the problem could lie, but am happy to put up additional information if anyone has any ideas why this is happening.

Comment: can you toss a rake routes in here for the destroy link please?

Comment: @ShawnWilson, as requested, added to the OP.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a reason your scoping the logout link? or just to clean up the url?

Comment: @ShawnWilson I got an error without it...

Comment: is the error coming from within your subdomain?

Comment: @ShawnWilson no, all this fresh hell is from the main domain. And right now there's no error, just a refusal to sign out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128558/discussion-between-shawn-wilson-and-liz).